# Accessible natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

A positive natural number is said to be accessible if it can be written as sum of poisitive integers whose sum of reciprocals adds up to $1$. It is easy to show that $3, 5 $ are not accessible while $4$ is. Is there a way to characterize all accessible positive integers, for example, an inductive process? It is clear that for any number $n$, the number of summands is at most $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ as all of these summands are greater than or equal to $2$. Is it possible to answer the problem in two cases: distinct and not necessarily distinct positive integers?

Please give some hint or reference.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you determine the first , lets say , $100$ accessible numbers ? Maybe, there is a pattern (although I have not much hope, to be honest).

Comment: @Peter No, verifying the 100 first of them, i think, needs a computer program as it is difficult to check by hand.

Comment: Well, what are the first few accessible numbers?  There certainly are some useful patterns.  If, say, $n=n_1+\cdots +n_k$ and $m=m_1+\cdots +m_l$ are accessible then $2(n+m)=2n_1+\cdots +2n_k+2m_1+\cdots +2m_l$ is as well.

Comment: It's easy to see for every perfect number $x$, $2x-1$ is accessible. At least that gives a subset. I wonder if that's all for the "distinct positive integers" case.

Comment: After finding the first, say, 5 such numbers, [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) might be of great help.

Comment: The sequence is [A125726](https://oeis.org/A125726).

Comment: @lulu on the complement OEIS entry [A028229](https://oeis.org/A028229), there is a comment that R.L.Graham has shown every number $\ge 78$ is strict-sense Egyptian...

Comment: @Fermat.  The $2n+2$ is a special case of what I wrote, taking $m=1$.

Comment: @achillehui  Ah, that makes sense.  Here I was, searching for a large non-Egyptian example.  Puzzled that I couldn't find one.  Thanks!

Comment: @lulu Ah, you are absolutely right.

Comment: Found a non-perfect-number "all-distinct" case: ${1\over 2}+{1\over 5}+{1\over 6}+{1\over 12}+{1\over 20}=1$, to append to my earlier comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are called Egyptian numbers in [OEIS A125726](http://oeis.org/A125726).  The first $73$ are given
$$1, 4, 9, 10, 11, 16, 17, 18, 20, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,\\ 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53,\\ 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73,\\ 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86$$ There are a couple references.  All the squares are there, as $n^2$ can be represented as $n\ n$'s.  If $n$ is in the list, so is $2n+2$ as you can double all the numbers in an expansion and add a $2$.  If $n$ is in the list with a $2$ in the expansion, so is $n+6$ because you can replace the $2$ with $4,4$.  The last one my eye sees missing is $23$.  [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EgyptianNumber.html) states that every number $\ge 78$ can be expressed this way with distinct numbers in the expansion and calls those numbers strictly Egyptian.  There is a link to the paper in the OEIS entry.

Comment: Thank you very much.